# Using rabbitmq-c as static library gives error: fatal error: amqp.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, rabbitmq-c

I am trying to build **rabbitmq-c** as a static library so I can use in AWS lambda.

I am able to build the examples following the documentation and those are working fine.

But now I am trying to use in my own project.
Below are the steps I took:

1. Cloned https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c inside **third-party** directory.
2. Inside my source directory, I am building using cmake.

Below is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
project(executable LANGUAGES CXX)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)

set(RABBITMQ_TARGET "<absolute_path_to_third_party_dir>/third_party/rabbitmq-c/")
add_definitions(-DAMQP_STATIC)
add_subdirectory(${RABBITMQ_TARGET})

include_directories(${LIBRABBITMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} execute_code.cpp)
target_link_libraries(executable PRIVATE ${RMQ_LIBRARY_TARGET})
```

3. I run `cmake .. -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` (which works without any issue).
4. But when I am executing **make**, it gives following error:

```
fatal error: amqp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/executable.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/executable.dir/execute_code.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/executable.dir/execute_code.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:169: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/executable.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/executable.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is my execute_code.cpp (I am removing unnecessary code just for here)

```
#include<iostream>
#include <amqp.h>
#include <amqp_tcp_socket.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char const *hostname;
  int port, status;
  char const *exchange;
  char const *bindingkey;
  amqp_socket_t *socket = NULL;
  amqp_connection_state_t conn;

  amqp_bytes_t queuename;

  conn = amqp_new_connection();
  socket = amqp_tcp_socket_new(conn);
  return 0;
}
```

when I am not using

```
#include <amqp.h>
#include <amqp_tcp_socket.h>
```

I am able to build rabbitmq-static, below is the make response

```
Scanning dependencies of target rabbitmq-static
[ 35%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_framing.c.o
[ 37%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_api.c.o
[ 40%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_connection.c.o
[ 42%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_mem.c.o
[ 44%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_socket.c.o
[ 46%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_table.c.o
[ 48%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_url.c.o
[ 51%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_tcp_socket.c.o
[ 53%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_time.c.o
[ 55%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_consumer.c.o
[ 57%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_openssl.c.o
[ 60%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_openssl_hostname_validation.c.o
[ 62%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_hostcheck.c.o
[ 64%] Building C object third_party/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq/CMakeFiles/rabbitmq-static.dir/amqp_openssl_bio.c.o
[ 66%] Linking C static library librabbitmq.a
[ 66%] Built target rabbitmq-static
```

It is able to generate **librabbitmq.a**, so it is able to build statically.

I tried with https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/releases/tag/v0.10.0 which is the latest stable version. But still the same error.

I tried searching regarding the issue, but couldn't find anything helpful.

I am pretty much newbie to cmake, Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you list the contents of the CMake variable `${LIBRABBITMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS}`? What does this variable contains? You can use `message(${LIBRABBITMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS})` to print its contents to the screen.

Comment: @squareskittles strangely this is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rabbitmq-c` repository sets the `LIBRABBITMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable in the `rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq` sub-directory, then also sets it using [`PARENT_SCOPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-normal-variable) so it is also available in the top-level `rabbitmq-c` directory. See that code [here](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/blob/26ecf6d3012be81f5dfb8a2d822c722e916a86cb/librabbitmq/CMakeLists.txt#L72):

> ```
> set(LIBRABBITMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS
>     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
>     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
>     ${SOCKET_IMPL}
>     ${MSINTTYPES_INCLUDE}
>     )
>
> include_directories(${LIBRABBITMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS})
>
> set(LIBRABBITMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS
>     ${LIBRABBITMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS}
>     PARENT_SCOPE)
> ```

However, when you include the `rabbitmq-c` repo in your project via `add_subdirectory`, it introduces an *additional* scope, and the `LIBRABBITMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable is not available in this parent-parent scope. You will have to either:

1. Re-organize your CMake project such that your project sits *within*
   the `rabbitmq-c` repository (although this is not scalable, and probably not what you want to do).
2. Modify the top-level `rabbitmq-c`
   CMake file to further extend the scope of this variable.
3. **Install** `rabbitmq-c` on your machine, and use a CMake [Find Module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules)
   or a CMake configuration file (e.g. `rabbitmq-c-config.cmake`)
   furnished by `rabbitmq-c` to locate the installed software.

Comment: I have installed rabbitmq-c in the system and it created librabbitmq.a inside /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ and include dir is /usr/local/include/. How do I use these inside my CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @ashutoshsharma In that case, you could add `/usr/local/include` to a `target_include_directories()` call, and  use `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librabbitmq.a` when you call `target_link_libraries()` to link to the library.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, I stumbled onto the same issue today.

None of the 3 solutions proposed by Kevin would suit my needs (the lib is declared as a submodule so I can't modify it, won't install on the production machines)

The solution for me was to add rabbitmq include directories to the target that links the lib :

```
target_include_directories("${PROJECT_NAME}" PUBLIC include/ path/to/rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq)
```